# Swift Inheritance v.s calling super

Tags: swift, inheritance, super, initializer

I was learning the following chapter in The Swift Programming Languages:

> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

Then I tried these codes in my target:

```
class Car {
    var name: String = "Unknown"
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
class RacingCar: Car {
    var speed = 0.0
    init(name: String, speed: Double) {
        self.speed = speed
        super.init(name: name)//this is where I got confused
    }
}
```

According to rule one, RacingCar class won't inherit the init(name:) designated initializer from its superclass Car. However, I'm still able to call the super.init(name:) in my subclass. How could that happen? I'm so confused about this. Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheriting a initializer means that that initializer is made available to instances of your **subclass** (that's what inheritance means); that is, your subclass' initializer can call it on `self`:

```
class RacingCar: Car {
    var speed = 0.0
    init(name: String, speed: Double) {
        self.speed = speed
        self.init(name: name) // <-- Error: This initializer is not inherited
    }
}
```

You don't need to inherit an initializer to call it on `super`: The superclass does not lose access to its initializer just because you subclassed it.

```
class RacingCar: Car {
    var speed = 0.0
    init(name: String, speed: Double) {
        self.speed = speed
        super.init(name: name) // <-- Works: super class does have this initializer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It makes sense, but I still have a question. Are all methods and properties defined in superclass available for subclass?@NicolasMiari

Comment: Yes, unless they are declared as `private`. But even then, they are still  available if both superclass and subclass are defined in the same file (in swift, access control is source file-based)

Comment: There are special rules regarding **initializers** (like you mention in your question), but other methods are inherited automatically.

Comment: Thanks again. Nice to have you here.@NicolasMiari

Comment: I myself am still quite new to swift too, and my answer might not be 100% correct. I suggest you wait a little while before accepting it. Something more deserving of it might come along.